# Issue On Setting Time Out/ Delay on For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please let me know how I can set timeout / Delay on following code:

```
$(function() {
  var alpha = Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","z");

  for ( var i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++ ) {

      $("#box").html(alpha[i].toUpperCase());
}
});
```

[Demo is Running here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/chq22av6/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
$.each(alpha, function (_, letter) {
    $("#box").delay(500).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).html(letter.toUpperCase());
        next();
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/chq22av6/1/

Comment: thanks elclanrs, just wondering if there is a way to do this with for loop?!

Comment: You could, but this is better than a `for` loop. jQuery has all you need so you don't have to use loops.

Comment: @Suffii A few things to note about this example, **1.:** `each()` and `queue()` both use for loops under the hood. **2.:** `delay()` uses `setTimeout()`. **3:** This example creates 52 jQuery objects for `#box`. You should consider caching your jQuery objects to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `window.setTimeout` recursively or use `window.setInterval`.

These both accept a callback method that will be called based on a timer (number of milliseconds).

Here is an example:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // ... do your work ...
    }, 1000 );
```

You can find [more information on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for you, just use setTimeout.

```
$(function() {
  var alapha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

    $.each(alapha, function (index, letter) {
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#box").html(letter.toUpperCase())}, index * 100);
    });
});
```

You can change from 100 to another value.. Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chq22av6/2/)..

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be best served by

> `window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...])`
>   
> Calls a function [...] repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. Returns an `intervalID`.

```js
$(function () {
    // pre-process the letter case transform
    var alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
    // cache your jQuery object so we're not recreating it 26 times
    var $box = $("#box");
    // index
    var i = 0;    
    // start an interval and store the id
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        // set element text
        $box.text(alpha[i++]);
        // stop the interval after we've processed 26 letters
        i > 25 && clearInterval(intervalID);
    }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

<sub>See also: [`clearInterval(intervalID)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval)</sub>